# unable to limit size in MergeContent in nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I will be getting files from a source which contains files around 1500 - 4000, which will come for every 5 mins(each file vary from 100kb to 8mb) so my requirement is i need to combine data which should not be more than 200mb si i have used merge content in nifi and given maximizing group size to 200 mb but still i am getting bigger files

my merge content screen shot [image]

can any one help with this much thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should set the maximum size in the "Maximum Group Size" parameter to 200 MB.
In the screenshot you added it seems that this property has no value given to it.